# Update Cell based on other cell Fieldcalculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

I want to search for certain values in a column. If that value is found, I want to update another a cell in the same row, other column.

I tried

```
CASE WHEN "column1" = 9 THEN "column2" = 'SA' ELSE "column2" END
```

That did not work. How would I approach that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using QGIS 2.16, in the field calculator, set it up to update an existing field (the one you want the changes to take place). Then write a CASE WHEN statement like this:

```
CASE WHEN "column1" = 9 THEN 'SA' ELSE "column2" END
```

You don't need to reference the column you wish to change as the field calculator takes care of that.

**EDIT:**

For multiple values change the expression to:

```
CASE 
WHEN "column1" = 9 THEN 'SA' 
WHEN "column1" = 8 THEN 'TB'
WHEN "column1" = 7 THEN 'UC'
ELSE "column2"
END
```

Comment: for multiple cases I can use `WHEN`?